# Adding custom HTTP header in Mule HTTP endpoint

Tags: http, mule, custom-headers

I am trying to add a custom header in Mule's HTTP endpoint:

```
<flow name="flow">
    <poll frequency="60000">
        <http:outbound-endpoint
            address="http://user:pass@example.com"
            followRedirects="true" method="GET" exchange-pattern="request-response">
            <properties>
                <spring:entry key="CUSTOM-HEADER-NAME" value="custom-header-value" />
            </properties>
        </http:outbound-endpoint>
    </poll>
    <echo-component />
</flow>
```

But this way of using `<spring:entry>` element for adding custom header does not seem to work.

I tried replacing

```
<properties>
    <spring:entry key="CUSTOM-HEADER-NAME" value="custom-header-value" />
</properties>
```

with

```
<property key="CUSTOM-HEADER-NAME" value="custom-header-value"/>
```

But that does not work either. I am not seeing any error, but the response I am getting is the one which I would get without the custom header.

Am I following the right way to add custom headers? I am using Mule 3.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working using `<message-properties-transformer>`:

```
<http:outbound-endpoint
    address="http://user:pass@example.com"
    followRedirects="true" method="GET" exchange-pattern="request-response">
    <message-properties-transformer
        scope="outbound">
        <add-message-property key="CUSTOM-HEADER-NAME"
            value="custom-header-value" />
        </message-properties-transformer>
</http:outbound-endpoint>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add custom header name from Mule .. there are 2 ways :-

1) Use Set property in your flow like :-

```
< set-property propertyName="Custom Header"  doc:name="Set Custom Header" value="Here Set your Message"/ >
```

2) Use SOAP intercepter where you have to create a java class  **HttpHeaderInterceptor.java** and then refer in the intercepter using Spring bean.. Please refer this :- http://java.dzone.com/articles/adding-http-headers-soap

Either way you can follow ... easy way is using set Property in mule flow Just before CXF SOAP component ....
The result you can see in **SOAP UI** in **header** section in response... 
Hope this help

Comment: I don't think `<set-property>` is a valid element in Mule 3.2. See the HTTP transport reference for 3.2 [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/HTTP+Transport+Reference#HTTPTransportReference-IncludingCustomHeaderProperties) and for 3.3 [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/33X/HTTP+Transport+Reference#HTTPTransportReference-IncludingCustomHeaderProperties).

Comment: Then try the second way ... Add the java class from the example given in the link as CXF interceptor